# Appending date/time to file AND updating last modified/save date

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I am trying to automate some file renaming but also need the file to update it's "last modified" time as I have a field inserted within the Word document that dynamically updates the last time the file was edited.

```
copy  C:\path\to\file\test\test.docx "C:\path\to\file\test2\test-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-4,4% %time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%.docx"
```

I tried to integrate the following syntax:
    `copy /b filename.ext +,,`

That I got from:
https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch/764716

However it did not output anything when I put the + after the source file.

```
copy /b "C:\path\to\file\test\test.docx" + "C:\path\to\file\test2\test- 
%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-4,4% %time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%.docx"
```

I also tried invoking a PowerShell script within the batch file to update last modified date:

```
$file = Get-Item C:\Path\TO\test.docx
$file.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)

copy C:\path\to\file\test\test.docx "C:\path\to\file\test2\test- 
%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-4,4% %time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%.docx"
powershell -file C:\path\to\powershell.ps1
```

Can't get it to work either way, I'm new to this so probably missing something simple.

Comment: A singe line PowerShell command `'C:\path\to\file\test\test.docx'|gi|copy-item -dest {'{0}\{1}-{2:MMddyyyy\ HHmm}{3}' -f $_.Directory,$_.Basename,$_.LastWriteTime,$_.Extension} -WhatIf` could be wrapped in a batch.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this one out. My batch file is now as follows:

```
powershell -command "(Get-Item "C:\path\to\file\test\test.docx").LastWriteTime = (Get- 
Date)"
copy C:\path\to\file\test\test.docx "C:\path\to\file\test2\test-%date:~-7,2%- 
%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-4,4%%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%.docx"
```

Which first modifies the last edited date of the file, and then copies it over to test 2 folder with the time and date appended.

Comment: Wondering how I can modify this without file paths specified so it just runs on files within a certain directory and creates a copy within the same folder with the time/date appended and modified date updated? 

To take it even further, can I change the "copy" command to "rename", modify the original files and then next time the script runs, it removes the PREVIOUS added date from the filename and adds the current one?

Comment: Update your question because now this is just too confusing in two places. As it stands we don't have enough details so make sure you put more details. For your question on how to do this without the full filepath... use pushd and popd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit curious what you mean with:

> I have a field inserted within the Word document that dynamically updates the last time the file was edited.

If you copy a file it's content is not altered and the LastWriteTime stays the same,
so why do you want to `set` LastWriteTime to current date&time?

As per your attempt with copy in cmd.exe you did omit the two commas, this should do:

```
copy /b "C:\path\to\file\test\test.docx" + , , "C:\path\to\file\test2\test-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-4,4% %time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%.docx"
```

The PowerShell suggestion from my comment:

```
'C:\path\to\file\test\test.docx' | 
 Get-Item |
  Copy-Item -Destination {'{0}\{1}-{2:MMddyyyy\ HHmm}{3}' -f `
                          $_.Directory, $_.Basename, 
                          $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

Could be modified to rename all files with date time appendix to reflect the actual `LastWriteTime`.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.docx | 
  Where BaseName -Match '-\d{8} \d{4}$' | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}-{1:MMddyyyy\ HHmm}{2}' -f `
                   $_.Basename.Replace($Matches[0],''),
                   $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

If the NewName is the same, Rename-Item ignores it.
In contrast to Copy-Item, Rename-Item doesn't allow a directory.

Comment: Tried your powershell one liner, albeit it saying it's copying the file, it doesn't actually create the file in the destination? Ran Powershell as admin as well, no dice. Wondering if its limitations in my workplace environment, will test at home later. Also, I need the file to update its last write time to the current time and then append the current time to a copied filename when I run the script (not append last write time to filename). I would use the rename option, but I'm not sure if it would strip the previous date(s) from filename before appending new one. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Well, I forget to mention to remove `-WhatIf` once you are satisfied with the output. The rename variant uses the `Where-Object` to store the trailing datetime (dash 8digits space 4 digits) in the automatic variable $Matches and removes it before applying the new datetime.